# why are facebook messenger and discord using databases and not queueing systems for their messages?

Tags: database-design, cassandra, architecture, message-queue, message

I'm reading the (pretty old) data design of [facebook messenger](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/the-underlying-technology-of-messages/454991608919/) and the newer design of [discord](https://medium.com/discord-engineering/how-discord-stores-billions-of-messages-7fa6ec7ee4c7).

Both use a wide-column database - hbase or cassandra. They are saying that:

> two general data patterns emerged:
>      1. A short set of temporal data that tends to be volatile
>      2. An ever-growing set of data that rarely gets accessed

I understand why the historic data is stored efficiently with that type of database, but how come the core functionality of sending the recent messages to the online users isn't implemented over something completely different: a queueing system such as kafka or rabbit?

Answer (score 0):

turns out they DO rely on a queuing system called iris, and the traditional storage system (cassandra/hbase) is just for retrieving old messages.
see https://engineering.fb.com/production-engineering/building-mobile-first-infrastructure-for-messenger/